# CasperJS tests worked on Windows 8.1, now they suddenly fail

Tags: windows, casperjs

I had a suite of 8 tests working great. Then, without changing them, they stopped working. They started working again for a while and now all fail every time.

Most of the code is very simple e.g.

```js
casper.test.begin('Assert title correct.', 1, function suite(test) {
    casper.start('http://localhost:49505/Default.aspx', function() {
        test.assertTitle("Flight Plan Guide: Search items", "Default page title is the one expected: Flight Plan Guide: Search items.");
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

I'm working on Windows 8.1.

My gut tells me this is a PhantomJS or other problem but I wanted to check if anyone had come across similar or had any advice on how to debug?

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't develop your web app further so that the tests should be adjusted? Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events or change to [debug mode](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#loglevel). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: Application has remained static. Thanks for the debugging pointers, I wasn't sure about that. I'll try them.